# Interpretation of spline models: plot vs estimate

Tags: r, regression, regression-strategies

I have conducted regression analyses (`cph` - using `rms` package) to investigate associations between an exposure (air pollutant) and disease risk. The predicted association (adjusted for a number of confounders) looks like this:

[image]

The solid red lines indicate p20-p80. This looks to me as if the 95% CI is so wide that there is no really any difference between p20 and p80. However, when I use the `summary.rms` command, I am told that the HR is 1.61 (1.14; 2.28):

```
summary(cph(ep ~ rcs(ep,3) + ..., data=data), ep=quantile(ep, prob=c(0.2,0.8)))
```

I assume that I made a mistake somewhere, but I'm not sure where.